AWS DMS Certificate for DocumentDB Elastic Cluster
When using AWS Database Migration Service (DMS) to connect to a DocumentDB Elastic cluster with SSL, is there a way to get access to a Certificate Authority file? The DocumentDB Instance-Based clusters provide the certificate authority file, and attempting to use the certificates from "openssl s_client -showcerts" or the global CA certificate bundle from a DocumentDB Instance-based cluster doesn't work (from a regular EC2 instance, MongoSH is able to connect with the OS trusted certificates).
